# Make light pass through plane in cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, lighting

I'm doing a bit of archviz for a buddy's bathroom remodel, and I want the windows and reflective surfaces to show a background without it darkening the scene. I think in 2.79 you could set the object to not cast shadows, but that seems to have been removed. I know I could use view layers, but A. I'm very confused by them, despite them ironically being made to supposedly be easier than the old method, and B. Next to a window is a glass plane that reflects the environment, and I don't know how I'd composite that in. I've also added in an external ground plane to get some ground color bounces.
[image: background]

[image: No Background]

Of note is the image with the background is blocking a lot of sun and sky light, so it's darker overall.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/how-to-illuminate-the-darkness-inside-glass-objects-in-cycles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40597/why-is-the-color-white-darkened-through-glass https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24256/node-setup-for-realistic-transparent-plastic/24261#24261

Comment: Why was this closed? It's not a duplicate, and the provided links for making glass shaders is not at all what I asked for. I have glass shaders, I need the reflections to reflect objects on a different view layer.